# The meaning of 技術は習うものではなく盗むもの

Tags: meaning, idioms

> 技術は習うものではなく盗むもの

I'm sure this is some sort of idiomatic expression, I just don't know exactly what it means. Searched everywhere but didn't find anything.

Sometimes the "Gijutsu" part is replaced by another thing, so I suppose the rest of the expression is the important bit.

To clarify, I know the literal meaning of the sentence "Technique isn't something you learn, it's something you steal". I just don't know what the expression entails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sentence means skills aren't taught but you learn them by yourself by watching old hands.

This sentence says learning skills by oneself by watching old hands is "steal skills"

Comment: Oh, I see!
That was very helpful, thank you!